# Is it possible to maintain a Stack Overflow for Teams user list (deactivate) via a REST API?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

I am trying to promote Stack Overflow for Teams within the company I work for and my manager asked about user management when there will a significant number of users (e.g. 1-2 hundreds). I know that users may easily join by specifying a list of allowed domain list (*.mycompany.com), but it is not clear how I can automatically inactivate a user when she leaves the company.

One way to deal with this is to read an all users list via an API and check them against an identity and access management system ([Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) or a custom one). Based on this query, I can deactivate whoever does not have an enabled account.

I have checked the [documentation that seem to address this issue](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams), but it is not clear how I can access the API:

- Obtaining an access_token seem to be covered [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), but it is not clear what flow should I follow. Should I register my team as [Stack App](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)?
- Also, Teams examples show `?scope=access_team%7cstackoverflow.com%2fc%2fpickles` as an example query. The base URL is api.stackexchange.com, isn't it?

Is is possible to maintain Stack Overflow for Teams user list (deactivate) via a REST API?

Comment: I noticed in your question you had some extra noise about how to access the API.  Your question isn't about that; it sounds like you should ask about that on Stack Apps instead.

Comment: @Makoto - you are right. However, that is still an issue for me and I will post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The API states that the data access is read-only.

> Starting with the release of Stack Overflow For Teams, the Stack Exchange API **exposes read-only access** to data stored in private Teams.

So no; you can't use the API *alone* to manage a user list and deactivate it.  It'd be an awesome feature, though.

Comment: This is not great news, as licensing costs are a real issue where I work and I should allow active users after leaving the company. However, I might play a little with Selenium Grid and automate the process (way more ugly and error-prone than using some APIs, but at least I can get what I want).

Comment: Forgot to ask. Even read-only access provides some value. How do I actually get a private key and toy around for my private site?

Comment: The documentation *should* cover that...

Comment: @Alexei Get an API token from StackApps, then [authenticate with your username](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and access the team as described. (I imagine.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I imagine it goes the same way, but I am not sure how to get such an API key. It seems that [this form](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) is related, but it deals with stackapps. Is this the way to get the API key to also be used to query data from the private team? It is strange that this flow has not been explicitly covered (or I cannot find where it has been).

Comment: @Alexei Yes, that's the way to get an API key. There's only one type of API key, afaik.