# When can we expect general users to "view" only?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I asked this probably 2-3 years ago and am having a hard time digging it up.  The question was is there a way other people (who do not have a license for teams) can get a read only view of a question / answer.  We have many questions in teams where I would like to share the result to a member who is from my organization but provides no content to the team site, their purpose would be a read only view.  I know I can copy and paste the content but sometimes that doesn't work out so nicely and plus sharing a link is so much cleaner.

Right now I cannot share any links to anyone in my company unless they have a license for teams - that doesn't meet most of our needs.  We'd be willing to pay for a "read only" license if that is an issue.  These types of users would not be able to edit or create or even delete content.  Their sole purpose is to share a link and allow them to look at an answer.

I think others would be looking for this option as well.  Can someone from the "Teams" team provide any further info if this is still being considered.  Back when Alex was working on teams he said it was something in the queue I believe.

Comment: I guess your only option today is use the API and publish the results on a website you own: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382821/578411

Comment: By closing this, I'm not intending to shut down your desire for this feature or prevent your desire for this feature from being communicated. However, starting out with asking *when something will be available* is, *at best*, premature. Before a timeframe can be known, there has to be agreement that it will happen. Prior to that, there needs to be agreement from the company that it's something that *should* happen. I recommend you either reformulate this question as a [meta-tag:feature-request] or create a new question asking for this feature.

Comment: I'd note that being on the receiving end of someone starting with "when will this happen" without any preliminary discussion about that thing happening, let alone without agreement that it both *should* happen and that it *will* happen, is *not* something that feels good, leaves a good impression, or that makes people predisposed to actually making whatever the thing is happen. I strongly recommend against using it as an opening gambit in requesting that something happen. OTOH: Something like "what can I do to make this happen and happen sooner" is a valid approach.

Comment: BTW: I did look through all of your Meta Stack Overflow questions which are tagged [meta-tag:stack-overflow-for-teams] and all of your [meta-tag:feature-request] posts going back to 2016. I found none where you requested this feature. However, I did find that you asked for: [Can we get “Print Friendly” versions of Teams questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380176/can-we-get-print-friendly-versions-of-teams-questions), which, while it appears to be attempting to solve a similar overall issue, isn't the same thing.